# gnome unity plugin has been disabled from ccsm

Tags: plugins

The unity plugin of ccsm has been disabled after I uninstall compiz and re-install again and it was replaced by viewport switcher. How can I re-install the unity plugin?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Have you tried clicking the checkbox next to the plugin to re-enable it?

Comment: yeah, and i found out that the problem is caused by unity,because it was not installed.

Comment: Would you mind putting your solution into an answer and accepting it? That way this question won't keep showing up in searches for unanswered questions.

Comment: sudo apt-get install unity

Answer (score 3):

*Answered by OP in a comment:*

> I found out that the problem is caused by unity,because it was not
>   installed. Installed it by
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install unity
> ```